# Function to rename column of each dataframe in a list to its dataframe name

Tags: r

I have a list of dataframes which have the same structure, but different values. I would like to rename one column in each dataframe to the dataframe name, so I can later merge these single columns into one dataframe, with a factor column.

Say that I wish to rename column 4 in mtcars.

```
mt1 <- mtcars
mt2 <- mtcars
mt3 <- mtcars

mtlist <- list (m1 = mt1,
                m2 = mt2,
                m3 = mt3)

change_column_name <- function(x) {
  aa <- deparse(substitute(x))
  names(x)[4] <- aa 
  return(x)
}

mtlist <- lapply(mtlist, change_column_name)
```

Instead of renaming column 4 to the dataframe name, it is renamed to X[[i]]. Renaming columns individually in this way outside a function works, so why is it not working when I put it inside a function?

Answer (score 2):

Reason is that within `lapply` your `change_column_name` is called with each element of `X` (which is in your case `mtlist`) that is with `X[[i]]` for `i = 1...3`. There are plenty of ways to achieve what you want, one solution would be the following:

```
mtlist <- list (mt1 = mt1,
                mt2 = mt2,
                mt3 = mt3)

change_column_name <- function(x, aList) {
  dat <- aList[[x]]
  names(dat)[4] <- x
  return(dat)
}

lapply(names(mtlist), change_column_name, mtlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve your expected output would be to pass input to function as list

```
change_column_name <- function(x) {
   names(x[[1]])[4] <- names(x) 
   return(x)
}

lapply(seq_along(mtlist), function(x) change_column_name(mtlist[x]))
```

Or use `Map` and pass names seperately

```
change_column_name <- function(x, y) {
   names(x)[4] <- y 
   return(x)
}

Map(change_column_name, mtlist, names(mtlist))
```

Comment: Well, this is not what the OP wanted. He wanted it to rename to the name of the `data.frame` and _not_ give all the 4th columns the same name.

Comment: @thothal yes, I realised that. I have corrected that.